# What is Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface?

Tags: windows, networking, ipconfig

Running ipconfig /all shows a Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface. What is that? Does this have something to do with IPv4 vs IPv6? Should I get rid of it? If so how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is to do with IPv6

All the gory details here: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/network/ipv6/teredo.mspx

Some people have had issues with it, and disabled it, but as a general rule, if it aint broke...

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some kind of really weird problem, keep it.  The number of IPv6 sites is very small, but there are some and it will let you get to them even if you're at an IPv4 only location.

If it is causing you a problem, it's best to fix it.  I've seen a number of people recommending removing it to solve problems.  However, they're not actually solving the root cause of the issue.  In all the cases I've seen, removing Teredo just happens to cause a side-effect that fixes their problem...  :)